# How to parse field to string with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a custom field in my `JSON` which is coming dynamic and needs to be parsed to struct which has a `HashMap` field like following:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: String,
    custom: HashMap<String, String>,
}

fn main() {
    let json_string = r#"{"field1":"3","custom":{"custom1":"15000","custom2":"60"}}"#;
    let my_struct = serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(json_string).unwrap();
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&my_struct).unwrap());
}
```

It works when my json string has string fields in custom field which can be easily parsed to string.

But the problem is my json string is:

```
let json_string_wrong = r#"{"field1":"3","custom":{"custom1":15000,"custom2":"60"}}"#; // Need to parse this
```

How to handle such castings in serde?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serde provides `serde_json::Value` ( [reference](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) ) . It is an enum which contains data types like:

```
pub enum Value {
    /// Represents a JSON null value.
    Null,
    /// Represents a JSON boolean.
    Bool(bool),

    /// Represents a JSON number, whether integer or floating point.
    Number(Number),

    /// Represents a JSON string.
    String(String),

    /// Represents a JSON array.
    Array(Vec<Value>),

    /// Represents a JSON object.
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

You can use `serde_json::Value` as a value type for your HashMap. It is simply possible to pull data from `serde_json::Value` with using [serde_json::from_value](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/fn.from_value.html) or use pattern matching. In your case i would use pattern matching, because only `Integer` types will be converted into a `String` and rest will be the same.

But you'll need to consider adding one more step after deserialize. Like

- <strike>Creating shadow field for `custom`, will be filled after deserialization.</strike>
- <strike>Or constructing new struct which contains `custom` as `HashMap<String, String>`.</strike>
- Add a function to convert `HashMap<String, Value>` to `HashMap<String, String>`,

---

Implementation of this trait can solve your problem.

```
trait ToStringStringMap {
    fn to_string_string_map(&self) -> HashMap<String, String>;
}

impl ToStringStringMap for HashMap<String, Value> {
    fn to_string_string_map(&self) -> HashMap<String, String> {
        self.iter()
            .map(|(k, v)| {
                let v = match v.clone() {
                    e @ Value::Number(_) | e @ Value::Bool(_) => e.to_string(),
                    Value::String(s) => s,
                    _ => {
                        println!(r#"Warning : Can not convert field : "{}'s value to String, It will be empty string."#, k);
                        "".to_string()
                    }
                };

                (k.clone(), v)
            })
            .collect()
    }
}
```

**Example**: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba1a9ca08e89a2517fd3c0fa025d86f6)

**Note**: Trait's name is not well chosen, suggestions are welcomed.